# WebSphere Liberty v16.0.0. 3 JAX-RS: QueryParams / PathParams mapping issue

Tags: java, jax-rs, websphere, websphere-liberty

With the following REST service definition:

```
@GET
@Path("/selection/{typeAssignation}/{numeroEmploye}")
public Response obtenirChoixSecteurs(@PathParam("typeAssignation") String typeAssignation,
                                     @PathParam("numeroEmploye") Long numeroEmploye,
                                     @QueryParam("confirme") @DefaultValue("true") Boolean confirme)
```

When the service is called with this URL:

```
<...>/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862?confirme=true
```

Liberty v16.0.0.3 throws a `NumberFormatException` and the client receives an HTTP 404 return code:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "206862?confirme=true"
```

It seems that liberty v16.0.0.3 is not able to assign the right values to the right PathParams / QueryParams even if it is able to select the right method based on the URL
The same code works perfectly well in WAS v8.5.5.9
Is this a bug in `cxf` embedded with Liberty (vs `wink` in WAS) ?

Comment: I would not recommend to receive typed values in the url, I would set everything as a string and parse it after.

Comment: Is there a reason why do you recommend to not use the standard REST API? Downvoted because this does not answer my problem at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andy, thanks for the pointer
In  WAS v8.5.5 the client is like this:

```
org.apache.wink.client.Resource resource;
resource = restClient.resource("<...>/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862?confirme=true");
```

In WLP v16.0.0.3 the client was translated to JAX-RS 2.0 like this:

```
  WebTarget  webTargetAST = restClient.target(<...>);
  WebTarget wt = webTargetAST.path("/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862?confirme=true");
```

Changing it to the following made it to work

```
  WebTarget  webTargetAST = restClient.target(<...>);
  WebTarget wt = webTargetAST.path("/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862");
  wt = wt.queryParam("confirme","true");
```

It seems that the JAX-RS in WLP encoded the `"?"` while wink in WAS v8.5.5 did not and it was not directly "visible" in the logs...
Thanks again

Comment: Rather than adding your own "answer" in response to another, you should add this as an update to your question, add a comment to Andy's answer, and then accept his answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: OK. but Andy's answer is not the answer to my problem,The answer to my problem is my own answer.. So what is the "official procedure" here? Accept my own question after updating it??

Comment: My apologies, I misinterpreted the issue.  Yes, if your answer is "correct" while Andy's just pointed yours in the right direction, then I believe you can accept your own answer.  I'm glad you figured out the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the GET request is getting messed up somehow.  When I built a JAX-RS resource using your method signature, everything worked as expected.  The only way I could reproduce a NumberFormatException was by putting a non-numeral character at the end of number (like "<...>/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862_?confirme=true").  It makes me think that your question mark is getting escaped or something.

Here is the code I used:

```
@GET
@Path("/selection/{typeAssignation}/{numeroEmploye}")
public Response obtenirChoixSecteurs(@PathParam("typeAssignation") String typeAssignation,
                                     @PathParam("numeroEmploye") Long numeroEmploye,
                                     @QueryParam("confirme") @DefaultValue("true") Boolean confirme) {

    String s =  "obtenirChoixSecteurs typeAssignation='" + typeAssignation + "' numeroEmploye=" + numeroEmploye + " confirme='" + confirme + "'";
    System.out.println(s);
    return Response.ok("success: " + s).build();
}
```

The output in the logs (and browser) was:

```
obtenirChoixSecteurs typeAssignation='HEBDOMADAIRE' numeroEmploye=206862 confirme='true'
```

I wonder if you might have more luck using the JAX-RS Client APIs to invoke the service, like:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9080/myApp/rest/res/selection/HEBDOMADAIRE/206862?confirme=true");
    System.out.println( target.request().get(String.class) );
```

The test client needs to be using the JAX-RS 2.0 APIs, but I was able to get a successful result with both jaxrs-1.1 and jaxrs-2.0 features using Liberty 16.0.0.3

A few other thoughts:

- Are you adding the resource class in you Application getClasses() method?  I don't think this is necessary with 2.0, but might be required for 1.1.
- Do you have any other providers, filters, interceptors, etc. that might be playing with the URL?

Hope this helps, Andy